# 2 Bulma questions - text absolute center and columns min-width

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

am new to Bulma and flex to be honest.

So i have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any nav burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(function ($el) {
      $el.addEventListener('click', function () {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        var target = $el.dataset.target;
        var $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Pacifico;
    src: url(fonts/pacifico/Pacifico-Regular.ttf);
}

.pacifico {
    font-family: Pacifico;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:red;
}

  .top_bg {background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20200113/pngtree-ornate-cross-rhombus-repeating-symmetric-dark-blue-blue-and-white-tile-image_327096.jpg"); background-repeat:repeat-x;}
  .top_bg  div {height:125px;}
  .bottom_bg {background-image: url("images/bg_bottom_repeat.jpeg"); background-repeat:repeat-x;}
  // .bird { background-image: url("images/bird.png"); background-position: 50% 30%; background-attachment: inherit;}
  .under {text-decoration:underline;}
  .navbar-item.is-mega {
  position: static;

  .is-mega-menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: .375rem 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>222</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="columns is-mobile is-centered is-vcentered top_bg mt-0 mb-0">
  <div class="column is-mobile pt-0 is-narrow"><img src="https://www.aiesec.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Captain-america-1.jpg" style="height:125px"></div>
  <div class="column has-text-centered"><span class="pacifico"><nobr>God save the Queen</nobr></span></div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">

    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <a class="navbar-item">1</a>
      <a class="navbar-item">2</a>
      <a class="navbar-item">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="columns mt-0 pt-0 mb-5">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column is-three-quarters"><img src="https://static.educalingo.com/img/en/800/african-elephant.jpg" class="box mr-5 is-pulled-left" style="width:20%;">
    <p class="mb-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dictum ullamcorper felis, nec maximus est suscipit nec. Proin vulputate rutrum metus id mattis. Proin eget sapien lacus. Phasellus a elit ante. Donec accumsan vel elit id malesuada. Sed et cursus massa. Nullam feugiat iaculis laoreet.</p>

<p class="mb-3">Curabitur tristique interdum luctus. Proin rutrum augue ac porta aliquet. Suspendisse quis iaculis dolor. Sed nec arcu sapien. Phasellus vitae convallis risus. Donec vel consectetur nulla, aliquet lacinia leo. Nullam vitae mauris dolor. Etiam ac malesuada tellus, id lacinia felis. Fusce ut turpis metus. Maecenas in interdum nulla. Quisque faucibus vitae est ut euismod. Nullam eu lorem elementum, tempor felis quis, maximus sem. Sed at ipsum fringilla, cursus nunc sed, ullamcorper elit. Aenean eget tortor quam.</p>

<p class="mb-3">Aliquam id ex efficitur quam faucibus bibendum a quis augue. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas neque lectus, sagittis vitae porta quis, consequat vel lorem. Aliquam vitae gravida justo. Aliquam at orci eget magna scelerisque lacinia. Mauris ornare tincidunt suscipit. Fusce scelerisque erat sit amet dui mattis facilisis. Etiam nec lectus rutrum, viverra purus ultricies, ullamcorper eros.</p>

<p class="mb-3">Suspendisse elementum justo ut enim imperdiet ultricies. Sed non dolor tincidunt, cursus nunc sed, fringilla ligula. Duis a commodo nulla. Fusce vulputate molestie porta. Pellentesque at ligula orci. Proin hendrerit commodo finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque eleifend gravida libero, sed bibendum sem pulvinar vitae.</p>

<p class="mb-3">Fusce sapien nulla, hendrerit et congue quis, hendrerit sit amet risus. Ut dignissim sodales nunc, sit amet viverra libero sagittis quis. Ut porta porta dolor, non aliquet massa faucibus id. Sed faucibus mollis mollis. Curabitur scelerisque lorem dolor, vitae aliquet magna aliquam vitae. Suspendisse est lorem, feugiat sit amet leo nec, vestibulum convallis quam. Praesent vitae arcu dapibus, euismod augue quis, bibendum ligula. Vestibulum quis eros dui. Donec pharetra sapien ligula, vel egestas est ornare ut. Suspendisse hendrerit, velit ut fringilla bibendum, velit elit congue neque, id rhoncus risus sapien vel ligula. Donec laoreet faucibus nulla, sed varius erat tincidunt sed. Donec vitae mi magna. Maecenas mollis facilisis tellus id convallis. Quisque sit amet egestas erat, tincidunt pretium metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla non laoreet lacus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The first question is how to center vertical text "God save the queen"? I've tried native Bulma classes as **is-vcentered** but no suсcess.

Second one - if my page is resized to a small mobile- size 2 columns that makes spaces at left / right in main section total disappear with no space left at all . Is there any build in classes for **min-width** or so?

We'll be appreciate for any kind of help.

Comment: Second question is very easy - is-mobile class for main text container solves the problem: <div class="columns mt-0 pt-0 mb-5 is-mobile">
  <div class="column"></div> ...

Comment: First question can be solved with padding-top but is it the only way?